# Grab Values between Slashes using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

> http://example.com/...../post/index/88/mike-hey-dddd

I need to grab the ##

> index/##/

"##" denotes numeric value.

I'm planning to run the regex is javascript.

Comment: And what regex have you tried?

Comment: Will that always be in the same spot?

Comment: Maybe: /\/index\/(\d+)\//g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `\/` to escape slashes you want to use in your regular expressions:

So the result would be:

```
var input = "http://example.com/...../post/index/88/mike-hey-dddd";

var match = input.match(/\/index\/(\d+)/i);

// Make sure to validate the result, as it might not
// match for a given alternative url.
var number = match ? match[1] : false;

alert(number);
```